# MySQL query shows error when calling a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am currently working on a longer MySQL-query and I check it step by step because of its length to find problems. Now I reached a point that I cannot explain to myself.

In my query I am calling a subquery with Select like Select(subquery). I used to "build" the subquery before and it worked. But when calling it - for further calculations - there's an error #1064 which has - as far as I can see - nothing to do with the subquery as opened braces are all closed and I used to address the subquery the way I did before. 
But the problem must have to do with the part around the query called avat and the following `Select(avat)`. The error is #1064, parsing error. Is it something new to learn for me, or something else?

```
SELECT sr.usr_id_give, 
       sr.usr_id_get, 
       IFNULL((sr.value / srgive.value),0) as asv,
       IF((SELECT asv) IS NULL,0.1,1)  AS sv,

(SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT y.usr_id2, x.usr_id2 FROM usr_connx x 
LEFT JOIN usr_connx y ON y.usr_id1 = x.usr_id2 AND y.usr_id2 <> x.usr_id1 
LEFT JOIN usr_connx z ON z.usr_id2 = y.usr_id2 AND z.usr_id1 = x.usr_id1 
WHERE x.usr_id1 = 3 AND z.usr_id1 IS NULL GROUP BY y.usr_id2 HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2),1.5,
IF(EXISTS(SELECT y.usr_id2, x.usr_id2 FROM usr_connx x 
LEFT JOIN usr_connx y ON y.usr_id1 = x.usr_id2 AND y.usr_id2 <> x.usr_id1 
LEFT JOIN usr_connx z ON z.usr_id2 = y.usr_id2 AND z.usr_id1 = x.usr_id1 
WHERE x.usr_id1 = 3 AND z.usr_id1 IS NULL GROUP BY y.usr_id2 HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2),0.5,0))) AS grade,
       ((SELECT sv) * (SELECT grade)) AS vat,

(SELECT AVG(value)
FROM (SELECT srr.value
FROM skill_ratings AS srr
WHERE srr.usr_id_get = 221 
AND srr.skill_id = 1
LIMIT 5) skill_ratings) as avat,

SELECT(avat)

FROM skill_ratings AS sr
LEFT JOIN skill_ratings srgive ON srgive.usr_id_get = sr.usr_id_give
WHERE sr.usr_id_get = 1
```

What I'd like to get done is that it works as it should, that I can call the subquery as it worked before I tried to call it.

Thanks in advance for your help. Probably, if it's a difficult problem, an explanation is welcome so that I can learn and avoid similar mistakes in the future.

Here's the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT(avat)

FROM skill_ratings AS sr
LEFT JOIN skill_ratings srgive ON srgi' at line 23
```

Comment: What about sharing with us the text related to the error?

Comment: @LelioFaieta, you are right. Added it right now. It's at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Remove  `SELECT(avat)` and the `,` at the end of the line before it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I know this works. But I need to select avat for the next step and calculations and want to solve it / make it work. Or may I misunderstand you?